# type casting problem with template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operator-overloading, type-conversion

I am not a template or type casting expert, so I really need some help.
I have to use an existing template class and encounter the following type cast problem.
I put some sample code to illustrtrate the problem.

```
//template class definition
template <class IntType>
class CUSTOMIZE_Int: public CUSTOMIZE_Type
{
 public:
     operator const IntType() const;  
 private:
     IntType m_int;
}

template<class IntType>
CUSTOMIZE_Int<IntType>::operator const IntType() const
{
   return m_int;  
}

// the template class instantiation
typedef CUSTOMIZE_Int<WRAPPER_Int32> CUSTOMIZE_UnsignedInt;
```

Then in my code, I derive a new class

```
// the derived class definition
class IntNum: public CUSTOMIZE_UnsignedInt
{
    // ctors and new methods;
}
```

and creat a variable, and try to make the conversion to get the data.

```
class IntNum& i;
const WRAPPER_Int32 j = i;
```

with the following compile error:

```
error: cannot convert "IntNum" to "const WRAPPER_Int32" in initialization.
```

What is the right way to do the conversion, or what is the problem with my code?
Thanks for any comments!

Comment: When I fix the trivial compiler errors (missing `;` etc., remove derivation from `CUSTOMIZE_Type`, provide a definition of `WRAPPER_Int32`, have `i` actually reference something), this compiles without issue with GCC 4.1.2 using `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -ansi`.  So there must be something you're not telling us!

Comment: Your code as written can't compile since you can't have an uninitialized reference. What does your actual code look like?

Comment: HI, Mark, thank you for the remark. just a quick feedback, I suspect "i" was initialized, otherwise, shouldn't it be another type of error (uninitialized reference i found, etc.)? Well, I will also investigate from this aspect

Comment: guys, thank you so much for your comments. There is one header file I forgot to include. Oli and Mark, I up-rate both of your comments.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you expect operator IntType()

```
class ...
    operator const IntType() const;  
}
```

to act here, when you assign i to j:

```
const WRAPPER_Int32 j = i;
```

However, this is not an implicit conversion, you must do it explicitely:

```
const WRAPPER_Int32 j = (WRAPPER_Int32) i;
```

Hope this helps.